# Expectation of a dt term

Tags: expected-value

I am working with Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman Equations and the following result appeared.

Suppose $V_t= \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$

and that $
E_{t}[Y]=E\left[Y \mid F_{t}\right]
$
,    where $F_t$ represents the information at time t

I do not understand why the following holds:

$E[V_t dt]=V_t$

You could write the expectation as an integral but this didn't clearify anything for me

Comment: Why do you believe that $E[V_t dt] = V_t$?

Comment: It is written in the book

Comment: I am guessing the book intended to write $E[V_t|F_t]=V_t$, assuming $V_t$ is $F_t$-measurable.